# How to make a particular record stay at the end of sql server database

Tags: sql, mfc

I am making a dialog based application in MFC, where in there is a need to read the database and display the contents from database, i managed to find the record and display it in a list box by comparing unique Id from edit box and database, but the problem is I cannot display the last record for some reason it's not happening, I am successfully able to display from 1 to n-1 so I decided to put nth record as dummy so I just need a method in which I can make that dummy record to always stay at the last or end of the database, 
Thank you

```
{
int flag = 0;
    CString ID;
    CDatabase database;
    CString sqlString=L"SELECT *FROM FM_REGISTER";
    wchar_t connstring[500] = L"Driver={SQL SERVER};Server=FCS-LOKANATH\\SQLEXPRESS;DataBase=FM;Integrated Security=True";
    database.Open(NULL, 0, 0, connstring);
    m_InfoID.GetWindowText(ID);
    m_InfoList.ResetContent();//this is a report command
        CRecordset recordset(&database);
        CString temp, record,temp2;
        recordset.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, sqlString, CRecordset::readOnly);
        while (!recordset.IsEOF()){//is null
            record = _T("");
            register int len = recordset.GetODBCFieldCount();
            for (register int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                recordset.GetFieldValue(i, temp);
                if (i == 0 & ID.CompareNoCase(temp) == -1)
                {
                    //MessageBox(L"Positive Macth");
                    flag = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    //MessageBox(L"Nagative Macth");
                    flag = 0;
                }
                record += temp + _T("|");
            }
            m_InfoList.AddString(record);
            recordset.MoveNext();
        }
    MessageBox(_T("Query done."), 0, 0);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

Comment: I think a more maintainable solution would be to solve the actual problem and determine why the last record isn't being read. Your workaround will undoubtedly cause more problems down the road. Maybe an off-by-one error, somewhere? Maybe post some code?

Comment: I agree with @wheatin.  You are trading one known problem for a whole host of unknown other problems, the first of which is what you are asking.  Best go back and figure out why the last record was not showing, and if you want help, post some code.

Comment: Add a date and time updated/created field to your table and order your query by that.

Comment: The problem is that i need to reorder the records for something else so ordering is not the best solution, tomorrow I will add the code tomo as its in office, thank you for the replies

Comment: you are creating "register int len = recordset.GetODBCFieldCount();" but you are not using it, why?

Answer (score 1):

OK, re-read and this didn't answer what you asked.

Post your code, we need to see how you are iterating the results.  The answer below is about ordering and not a missing record.

You can do this with an order by on your query.

`SELECT id, description, order FROM mytable ORDER BY order ASC`

This will cause the query to be retrieved ordered by the `order` column, and you just need to make sure that the order in the database is largest for the record you want to appear last.